# How to enter minibuffer for editing in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

When running certain commands, the mini-buffer asks input strings, (e.g. the C-M-s).

Sometimes I need to enter complex strings into minibuffer. Therefore, I need to use movement commands such as C-f, C-b, C-a, etc. However, these does not work when I am entering string inside command <kbd>C-M-s</kbd>.

So, what is the general command / key-bindings for me to focus point in mini-buffer for extended movement support?

---

Edit:

I just discovered that M-e will work for searching commands. But I am not sure whether this command is the general command to "switch from buffer to minibuffer for dedicated editing"

Comment: `isearch-edit-string` is a special animal.  When using the normal isearch forwards or backwards, the user is not really inside the mini-buffer -- it just looks that way.  `isearch-edit-string` places focus squarely inside the mini-buffer for editing.  You are probably thinking of something like `read-sring`, etc.

Comment: @lawlist, thanks for the tips. Let me play with the code for a while

Comment: Isearch is pretty much the only thing that is "kind of in the minibuffer but not really".  There might be others, but this is not standardized, so there's no general "really go to the minibuffer".  Each case should hoefully provide the equivalent of Isearch's `M-e`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, `M-e` is what you are looking for, if you want to edit the search string. It lets you perform general editing on it. Just hit `C-s` or `C-M-s` again  when you are ready to search for the edited string.
2. However, `M-e` is only for editing the search string. If you instead want to interrupt isearch to do some editing somewhere, then just end isearch to do that, and then resume isearch when done editing, by using `C-s` or `C-M-s` again.

Answer (score 1):

I have been happy using these and I bind them to the function button and arrow keys on my Mac keyboard.  I frequently block and copy text and move in and out of the mini-buffer.  The following example frees up some of the keymap assignments in the `minibuffer-local-map` and `minibuffer-local-completion-map` (i.e., by setting them to `nil`) so that I can use my own custom keyboard shortcuts to enter and exit the mini-buffer.

From inside the mini-buffer, you can use `C-h k` and then the type the keyboard shortcut to see what function is bound.

When I switch in and out of the mini-buffer window, I use a custom function that changes the mode-line color, and mini-buffer prompt color, and default color inside the mini-buffer, but that is beyond the scope of your question.  [I just add the name of my mini-buffer color change function at the tail end of the following four functions -- i.e., after the if / then statements.]

```lisp
(defun lawlist-windmove-right ()
(interactive)
  (if (window-in-direction 'right)
    (select-window (window-in-direction 'right))
    (other-window 1)))

(defun lawlist-windmove-left ()
(interactive)
  (if (window-in-direction 'left)
    (select-window (window-in-direction 'left))
    (other-window -1)))

(defun lawlist-windmove-up ()
(interactive)
  (if (window-in-direction 'above)
    (select-window (window-in-direction 'above))
    (other-window 1)))

(defun lawlist-windmove-down ()
(interactive)
  (if (window-in-direction 'below)
    (select-window (window-in-direction 'below))
    (other-window -1)))

(define-key minibuffer-local-map [prior] nil)
(define-key minibuffer-local-map [next] nil)
(define-key minibuffer-local-map [home] nil)
(define-key minibuffer-local-map [end] nil)
(define-key minibuffer-local-completion-map [prior] nil)
(define-key minibuffer-local-completion-map [next] nil)
(define-key minibuffer-local-completion-map [home] nil)
(define-key minibuffer-local-completion-map [end] nil) 

(global-set-key (kbd "<end>") 'lawlist-windmove-right)

(global-set-key (kbd "<home>") 'lawlist-windmove-left)

(global-set-key (kbd "<prior>") 'lawlist-windmove-up)

(global-set-key (kbd "<next>") 'lawlist-windmove-down)
```

Comment: thanks for the code. It is nice to learn a way for quicker switching between windows, include but not limited to mini-buffer.